# Editing / disallowing certain values in input fields

Tags: configuration

Is there a way in CIVICRM to not allow certain values in input fields?  For instance, I do not want folks to put "Self-Employed" in the Organization field of an organization contact.

Answer (score 1):

For something that specific you'd need to write an extension. It would be a small one though, where you just use [hook_civicrm_validateForm](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_validateForm) to check the value and reject it.